# Style on a selected tab

Tags: html, css

I have this piece of code:

```css
.tab-menu .tabs {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.tab-menu .tabs button {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 14px 16px;
}

.tab-menu .tab-section .tab {
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-menu">
    <div class="tabs">
        <button class="tabLink">tab</button>
    </div>
        
    <div class="tab-section">
        <div class="tab">
            data
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This piece of code give this:

[image]

But i wan't to delete the part mark on red on the picture, how can I do it?

Comment: `.tabLink { margin-bottom: -1px; }` might do the trick.

Comment: the bar come from `.tab`, not from `.tabLink`.

Comment: Alright, well, then `.tab { margin-bottom: -1px; }` might do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the border you are trying to remove is only 1 pixel wide, you can just move `.tabs` a pixel lower with `transform: translateY(1px)` to give the illusion of the two divs being connected.

```css
.tab-menu .tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(1px);
}

.tab-menu .tabs button {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

.tab-menu .tab-section .tab {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-menu">
  <div class="tabs">
    <button class="tabLink">tab</button>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-section">
    <div class="tab">
      data
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your tab buttons already have a white background, you can simply pull them down by one pixel, so they overlap the tab section's top border. Adding `margin-bottom: -1px` is one way to achieve this.

```css
.tab-menu .tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.tab-menu .tabs button {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

.tab-menu .tab-section .tab {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-menu">
  <div class="tabs">
    <button class="tabLink">tab</button>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-section">
    <div class="tab">
      data
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```